# How can I get 10 posts from a particular category (myCategory) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

1. In Wordpress I need to get the posts form myCategory as blog post (with the meta data example date, posted by etc)- this is working fine but currently bringing back all the post from every category

   ```
           switch ($page_layout) {

               case "layout-sidebar-single-left": 
                       echo '<div class="row fixed">';
                           echo '<div class="col-220 no-print">';
                               ewf_setSection('zone-sidebar');
                               if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')  || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-page') );
                           echo '</div>';

                           echo '<div class="col-700 last">';


                                   $postTitle = '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>' ;  
                                   $readMore = '<p class="text-right"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.__('Read More', EWF_SETUP_THEME_DOMAIN).'</a></p>';
                                   query_posts('category_name=media&showposts=2');
                                   if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post();    
                                       echo $postTitle;
                                       echo the_content();
                                       echo $readMore;
                                   endwhile; 



                           echo '</div>';
                       echo '</div>';

               break;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
query_posts(array('category_name'=>'Category Name','posts_per_page'=>10));
// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content( 'Read the full post »' );
endwhile;
```

Comment: This brings back the posts from the category but the read more tag and the title of the post are no longs links to the full post. the posts use the <!--more--> tag to create excerpts.

Comment: Sorry, but this way is supposed to work. You can use the_permalink and the_excerpt as well to output what do you need.

Comment: I've used the code above with the_permalink but the title seems to bring back the page title rather than the post title. sorry not very good with php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $args = array(
            'category_name'=>'MyCategory',
            'posts_per_page'=>10);

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      // display stuff here
     endwhile;
```

This is the query that will get you 10 posts from a category named MyCategory - just copy/paste your current code that renders the HTML for the date/author/whatever you already have in the commented part.

It's the part inside your current loop